# multisite: allow only specific users to update sites

Tags: multisite, upgrade

We run a 20+site WPMU, and have ~16 super admins.  Today we made a new admin and before we could even talk to her, she updated the site to 3.8, which we weren't on yet due to lots of silly bureaucratic reasons. I am personally grateful she updated, but we can't let this happen again.

Is it possible to turn off the ability for site admins to update and throw a global function on the site that only allows specific users to upgrade?

The only idea I have so far is to hide the update bar in the CSS and show it for the specific users.

Comment: ... a trigger happy superadmin ;-) But this is possible a dublicate of [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55740/restrict-admin-capabilities-in-multisite)

Comment: @birgire I leave it open search results as it's more specific.

Comment: @kaiser sure, but it looks like the provided answer solves both question - so maybe I was too *trigger happy* on the close vote here ;-)

Comment: Rethought it, read the other answer again. Closed it. You were right @birgire